# Dropdown menu won't extend beyond navbar in xs size viewport

Tags: drop-down-menu

First ever question on here so go easy... (can you smell fear through the internet??) Okay, so my dropdown menu works fine in a desktop size viewport but viewing it through developer tools in mobile size it gets clipped and won't extend beyond the bottom of the nav div. What gives, yo? Here's the code, which I understand is the accepted protocol...

```
<!--start of navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid"><!--stretches navbar full width of screen-->

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!--hamburger collapse menu-->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><!--sr-only is for people with vision impairment-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span><!--triple lines on burger menu-->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="homelink navbar-brand" href="#">Michael Amos</a>

        </div> <!--/nav header-->

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> <!--make navbar list collapse when resize for small screen-->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><!--applies bootstrap styling to float navbar items right-->
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">work<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#work">example 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#work2">example 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#work3">example 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!--/nav collapse-->
    </div> <!--/container-fluid-->
</nav> <!--/navbar-->
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ooh! I forgot- here's a bitballoon link to the website so you can see the problem: http://typist-sharon-87827.bitballoon.com